# eclipse intellisense doesn't show methods of class (shows only constants)

Tags: eclipse

All!

When I type name XMLReader:: intellisense eclipse shows only constants of this class and doesn't show methods. My question is "Why this is so?", and second question is "Could I do something that intellisense eclipse shows me methods of this class?"

Thanks

Comment: What language are you programming in? Is the "::" correct syntax for that language? Also, note that instance methods won't be shown if you use the syntax for static members.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about PHP, there are no static methods in XMLReader. If you write code like
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->
You will get methods list as "Content Assist" (Intellisense is not a term of Eclipse).